# select count of min of a field when other field should does not duplicate

Tags: sql

I have some columns and one is username and its value is duplicated and credit field have some value I have to find count(username) without duplication while its credit field is between two value.

```
username |credit  
john     |2000
mary     |5000
john     |1000
john     |400
mary     |3670
```

I want to know how many user I have which min(credit) is between 2700 and 4000

I used:

```
select count(distinct(username)) having min(credit)
```

but it is not correct

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text). Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps:

1. Find users with  min(credit) between 2700 and 4000 (for which you must group by user so as to be able to know their minimum credit).
2. Count these users.

The query:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select username
  from mytable
  group by username
  having min(credit) between 2700 and 4000
) selected_users;
```